# VLOOKUP for different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have value in Sheet1 "B" column which is to be vlookup in Sheet2 from Column "A to K" and copy the corresponding C column value of Sheet2 and paste it in Sheet1's E column.

I have tried with below code but it shows error as

Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the Vlookup Property of the worksheetfunction class.

```
Sub vlook_up()
  For i = 2 To 11
       Cells("D" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:K500"), 3, 0)
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, however I feel you are passing the function an inappropriate var type.

```
Sub vlook_up()
  For i = 2 To 11
       Range("D" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:K500"), 3, False), "error")
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply@Lowpar

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Sub vlook_up()
  For i = 2 To 11
       Range("D" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:K500"), 3, False);
  Next i
End Sub
```

or

```
 Sub vlook_up()
      For i = 2 To 11
           Range("D" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:K500"), 3, False);
      Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response@Karthick